# How can I make my dropdown be above my content?

Tags: html, css, z-index

This is my website: https://zarmdev.github.io/To-doz/index.html

When I hover over the +, it doesn't overlap the panes (the squares with text).

I gave it and it's parent a z-index of 10 and the panes a z-index of 0.

[image]

CSS for the pane

```
.pane {
  background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  border: solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.463) 2px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 2vw;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 14ch;
  height: 15ch;
  mix-blend-mode: darken !important;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.404) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.7;
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
  z-index: 0; /* Z-index set here */
}
```

CSS for the dropdown

```
#dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 10;
}

#dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.534);
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 8px 12px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

To see for yourself, first hover over the + button and press the other + button a few times.

When changing background color.

[image]

ALSO: When I try to hover on the other buttons, it disappears because it overlaps and thinks im hovering the pane.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#dropdown` is partly transparent, that's why the stuff behind is visible: You defined `background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.534);` for it - the "0.534" value in there is the transparency value.

Change that value to avoid that.

Comment: Doesn't work. It still overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

Check here a tuto with dinamic and online examples:
[z-index tutorial and examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

as a complementary solution, in the screenshot it is seen that applying z-index -1 works
[the solution with z-index: -1 worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC1tI.png)

Comment: Please try to write down the solutions with explanations rather than sending tutorials links.

Comment: the solution with z-index: -1 worked for me

Comment: You need to write down the solution instead of pasting a link. You might include a reference link in your answer. Not a tutorial link though !

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i have added a screenshot to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try change **z-index** property of your `.pane` class to value -1.

```
.pane {
  background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  border: solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.463) 2px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 2vw;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 14ch;
  height: 15ch;
  mix-blend-mode: darken !important;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.404) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.7;
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
  z-index: -1; /* Z-index set here */
}
```